# Bootstrap alert and close button functionality without CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button, alert

I would like the Bootstrap alert and close button functionality. I've included the JQuery and Bootstrap javascript file in my page head but don not want the CSS in it because it overrides a ton of styling.

Currently I've added these parts of the Bootstrap to my own css to make the alert and close button appear.

```
.alert {
    padding: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px
}

.alert h4 {
    margin-top: 0;
    color: inherit
}

.alert .alert-link {
    font-weight: 700
}

.alert>p,
.alert>ul {
    margin-bottom: 0
}

.alert>p+p {
    margin-top: 5px
}

.alert-dismissable,
.alert-dismissible {
    padding-right: 35px
}

.alert-dismissable .close,
.alert-dismissible .close {
    position: relative;
    top: -2px;
    right: -21px;
    color: inherit
}

.alert-info {
    color: #31708f;
    background-color: #d9edf7;
    border-color: #bce8f1
}

.alert-info hr {
    border-top-color: #a6e1ec
}

.alert-info .alert-link {
    color: #245269
}

.alert-danger {
    color: #a94442;
    background-color: #f2dede;
    border-color: #ebccd1
}

.alert-danger hr {
    border-top-color: #e4b9c0
}

.alert-danger .alert-link {
    color: #843534
}

@-webkit-keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
    from {
        background-position: 40px 0
    }
    to {
        background-position: 0 0
    }
}

@-o-keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
    from {
        background-position: 40px 0
    }
    to {
        background-position: 0 0
    }
}

@keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
    from {
        background-position: 40px 0
    }
    to {
        background-position: 0 0
    }
}
```

This CSS makes the alert work as expected. The below part is for the close button. It styling has changed a bit, but I seem to be missing a few lines of CSS. Can anyone tell me which onesm can't seem to find them.

```
button.close { -webkit-appearance:none;padding:0;cursor:pointer;background:0;border:0}
```

Target HTML:

```
<% if (message.length > 0) { %>
    <div class="alert alert-info"><%= message %><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button></div>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Put your custom css after bootstrap css in the head section. In this way your css override bootstrap.

Comment: It does override =) Just looking for a way to know exactly what css lines I need from the Bootstrap css to mimick the close buton.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML (added `alert-dismissable` class, changed `x` to `×`):

```
<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissable">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
  Message
</div>
```

CSS (added basic styles for `close` class):

```
.close {
  float: right;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
  filter: alpha(opacity=20);
  opacity: .2;
}
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  opacity: .5;
}
```

### [CODEPEN EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvVpvX)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Any tips on how to find this myself in the future?

Comment: Best way is to use for example Web Developer Tools in Chrome and inspect element in Bootstrap documentation and check what styles are applied to elements.